# Sum of reciprocals of squared and factoriels

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find out the answer to sum of reciprocals of multiplication of $n!$ and $2^n$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!(2^n)}.$$

Comment: your sum should be $$\sqrt{e}-1$$

Comment: Can you please give me a hint how did you calculate it ?

Comment: should be ?well this is math

Answer (score 2):

It is, hopefully, a well known result that
$$ \mathrm{e}^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
Your series can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n! 2^n}
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^n }{n!} \\
&= \left[ 
\frac{ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^0 }{0!} \color{red}{- \frac{ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^0 }{0!}}\right] + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^n }{n!} && (\text{add zero}) \\
&= \color{red}{-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^n }{n!} \\
&= -1 + \mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{2}} && (\text{use the well known result}) \\
&= \sqrt{\mathrm{e}} -1.
\end{align}

Comment: Can't believe it took 9 months for someone to give a good answer.  Poor OP!  Nice answer though.

Comment: Oh, man, I didn't even notice how old the question was.  Heh.

Answer (score -1):

Maclauren exspansion of sqrt e is sum(1/(n! * 2**n) , 0 < n < infinity. This is an identity. You specified starting at one, the sum of terms lack one.
hence, sqrt e -1 is sum(1/(n! * 2**n) , 1 < n < infinity.
ref. and google  https://oeis.org/wiki/Sqrt(e) and Maclauren exspansion.